# How to handle null data when null is returned

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have the code below that is returning data for me. If result equals "Success" then there is data. I am not getting any data 
    back but getting a null. Data is diplayed on a web grid and when the webgrid sees that the data is Null, the page crashes.

How can I handle null from here?

```
        public Chemicalsdetails GetChemicalDataGeneratedForMonth(string branchcode, string departmentnumber, string previousMonth, string currentMonth)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                result = _chemmeterprocessor.CopyPreviousMonthData(branchcode, departmentnumber, previousMonth, currentMonth);
                Chemicalsdetails objChem = null;

                if (result == "Success")
                {
                    objChem = new Chemicalsdetails();
                    List<Chemicaltransactiondto> objAllData = new List<Chemicaltransactiondto>();
                    objAllData = _chemmeterprocessor.GetAllChemicalEntries(branchcode, departmentnumber, currentMonth);
                    objChem.GetAllChemicalsInformation = objAllData;                
                }
                else
                {
                    Chemicalsdetails objNoData = new Chemicalsdetails();                 
                }

                return objChem; 
            }
```

Comment: I see contradicting statements 'not getting data' and 'data is displayed in the grid. Are you trying to say result is "Success" and object 'objAllData' has data. Can u pls elaborate

Comment: I see. Not getting data back means I am getting null back and "Data is displayed on a web grid" should be Data returned should be displayed on a web grid and null is coming back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for null after you retrieve your data.

```
        public Chemicalsdetails GetChemicalDataGeneratedForMonth(string branchcode, string departmentnumber, string previousMonth, string currentMonth)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                result = _chemmeterprocessor.CopyPreviousMonthData(branchcode, departmentnumber, previousMonth, currentMonth);
                Chemicalsdetails objChem = null;

                List<Chemicaltransactiondto> objAllData = new List<Chemicaltransactiondto>();

                //****Check for "Success"
                if (result == "Success")
                {
                    //****Retrieve chemical data
                    objAllData = _chemmeterprocessor.GetAllChemicalEntries(branchcode, departmentnumber, currentMonth);
                    //****End Retrieve chemical data
                }

                //****Check for non-null data.
                if ((result == "Success") && (objAllData!=null))
                {
                    objChem = new Chemicalsdetails();

                    objChem.GetAllChemicalsInformation = objAllData;                
                }
                else
                {
                    Chemicalsdetails objNoData = new Chemicalsdetails();                 
                }

                return objChem; 
            }
```